# How to alternate row color in a table when cell value changes?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, excel-tables

I have a spreadsheet that brings in a table of data via Power Query.
Every time there is a refresh, the table length may change.

I need columns C and D to alternate highlight colors when the value is not the same as the previous row.

How the table should look each time it is refreshed through Power Query and the VBA code runs.
[image: Here is the screenshot from my worksheet]

Comment: I would use conditional formatting to [shade alternating rows](https://www.lifewire.com/shade-alternate-rows-with-excel-conditional-formatting-4178628) as probably easier than adding that code to VBA.

Comment: @PeterT: Your link is formatting every other row and is not looking for the values as the OP asks

Comment: I tried using conditional formatting, but every time the table is updated it messes up the references and breaks the formula in the conditional formatting.

Comment: Just for curiosity: How did this conditional formatting looked like? Maybe you can add that to your question and show why it fails.

Comment: I created a helper column with 1s and 0s based on the row value. Every time the table is updated, it is bringing in new data and changes the number of rows in the table (sometimes less or more than the previous import). When that happens the formulas jump around based on where the previous imported table stopped at regardless of me locking the refernce cells in the formula.

Comment: You could add that helper column and conditional formatting via VBA after the table is updated.

Comment: @Ike Could you also help me with the code for adding in the helper column? This is the formula I was using MOD(IF(C2=C1,F1,F1+1),2)); where F1 had a value of zero.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA to apply the format condition for the alternating coloring would be:

```vb
Public Sub alternatingColorSizeAndKind(rg As Range)

Dim fc As FormatCondition
With rg.FormatConditions
    .Delete
    Set fc = .Add(xlExpression, , "=($C1=$C2)+($C2=$C3)")
    fc.Interior.Color = 14348258
    
    Set fc = .Add(xlExpression, , "=($C1<>$C2)")
    fc.Interior.Color = 13431551
End With
    
End Sub
```

You have to pass the range of your table to this sub.

If you have a listobject/table then you call it like this:

```vb
Public Sub update()


Dim lo As ListObject
'>>> adjust the names to your needs
Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Pull_Data")

alternatingColorSizeAndKind lo.DataBodyRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to VBA. Is there a way to reference the table itself instead of a range of cells? The table name is 'Pull_Data'. How would I put that in the code you provided?

Comment: I added the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Attempt with conditional formatting:
(Note: This will work correctly only if a value cannot appear later down that list).

Create a rule (or two rules, to be precise) based on a formula. According to your screenshot, I assume that your data starts at row 3 and you want to look at column C.
There is a rather easy formula that you can use to count the number of unique values of a list. The base formula was "borrowed" from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif) and is `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))`. The trick now is that you look to the range from the beginning of the list to the actual row by using the range `C$3:C3`. If you copy the formula down, the start row remains while the end row is changed. Now simple put a `IsOdd` resp `IsEven` around the formula.

So the formula is `=ISODD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C$3:C3,C$3:C3)))` for the "green" rows and `=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C$3:C3,C$3:C3)))` for the yellow. Apply the rule to the range `=$C$3:$C$1048576`

However, I don't know if this conditional formatting will "survive" an update of the query.

[image]

**(2)**
Formatting with VBA is simple. The following code formats one column of an table (a table in VBA is the type `ListObject`. Pass the listobject and the column number as parameter:

```
Sub ColorRows(table As ListObject, columnNumber As Long)
    Dim cell As Range, isOdd As Boolean
    For Each cell In table.DataBodyRange.Columns(columnNumber).Cells
        With cell
            If .Offset(-1, 0) <> .Value Then isOdd = Not isOdd
            ' On a standard Office color scheme, 10 is kind of green and 8 is a dirty yellow
            .Interior.ThemeColor = IIf(isOdd, 10, 8)
            .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.8
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

This is how the call could look like (adapt the sheet and the listObject to your needs):

```
Sub test()
    ColorRows ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1), 3
End Sub
```

Now calling this code automatically is a different story and unfortunately rather complicated - if you want/need, try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+QueryTable+After+Refresh for some insights.  An easy alternative is to trigger the formatting manually, eg by placing a button (or a shape) on your sheet that calls the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the code to work. Where can I find a list of how to change the highlight color? I have a few more tabs I need to do this to that need different colors.

Comment: Easiest way is to fill a cell on the sheet with the color you want, than use the immediate window in the vba editor: `?selection.interior.color` this will give you the color code to use

Comment: To add what Ike wrote: There are three different ways to specify a color. `Color` gives the RGB-Value (as `Long`). `ColorIndex` is an index into an color palette, this was used before  RGB was possible in Excel. `ThemeColor` is a number that represents a color from your current Theme (and `TintAndShade` changes the brightness). When you use `ThemeColor` and change your Excel theme, the visible color will automatically change, while when you use `Color`, the color will stay unchanged.